# Failed to allocate a 105949236 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 40MB until OOM

Tags: android, google-maps, out-of-memory

I am getting the following error when I am trying to move to a maps activity in my android app. I have tried loads of different ways to fix it by reading other similar questions but I am unable to fix it. If anyone can please help, Thank you.

This is the error in the log file I am receiving.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.neil.studicom, PID: 30587
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 105949236 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 40MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:726)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:547)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:575)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:605)
    at com.example.neil.studicom.MapsActivity.resizeMapIcons(MapsActivity.java:42)
    at com.example.neil.studicom.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:53)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzo$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.v$a$a.a(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:82)
    at maps.ei.bu$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

     /* dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }*/

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.neil.studicom"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    /*compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.1'*/
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}
```

Comment: post you build.gradle file

Comment: possibly because you are using all the google services.. Use what only you need.. and also enable large heap

Comment: I have posted my gradle file, thank you.

Comment: Is your issue fixed ? @Dom

Comment: No it is still crashing the app. I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: try add <application android:largeHeap="true" in your manifest.it may solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `resizeMapIcons()` method is attempting to use `decodeResource()`, and that is triggering a 105949236-byte allocation. That is ~100MB. It is equivalent to a 5146px by 5146px image. No Android *screen* is that size; you certainly do not need an *icon* that large.

You need to find this resource and drastically reduce its resolution.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The wrong image had been used.

Comment: sqrt(105949236/4) = 5146px  (4 is from 1 byte per rgba channel)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

and add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
```

and in your gradle

```
dexOptions {
    //incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
}
```

This is because the services contains all the libraries which you might not be needing for the project..So use what you exactly need

also refer [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)

Comment: Is the gradle part necessary?

Comment: I have followed these steps and nothing has changed unfortunately.